# How to create schema model depend on have data element on mongoDB in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to create dynamically schema element depend on data have in Nodejs for MongoDB ? Which syntax can use for create, add , update data object element like as the follow json format.

```json
  WorkTasks: [
    {
      PerformedBy: "Joe",
      StartDate: 2021-07-19T17:43:06.693+00:00,
      EndDate: 2021-07-19T17:43:06.693+00:00,
      Remarks: "Pad error",
      Failure: "DDPP 20 - 090"
    },
    {
      PerformedBy: "Karen",
      StartDate: 2021-07-19T17:43:06.693+00:00
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, the question is very unclear please use this guideline on how to ask good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

From [Node.js Best Practices](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices):

> Though validation can be coded or relied upon classes and types
> (TypeScript, ES6 classes) the community seems to increasingly like
> JSON-based schemas as these allow declaring complex rules without
> coding and share the expectations with the frontend. JSON-schema is an
> emerging standard that is supported by many npm libraries and tools
> (e.g. jsonschema, Postman), joi is also highly popular with sweet
> syntax. Typically JSON syntax can't cover all validation scenario and
> custom code or pre-baked validation frameworks like validator.js come
> in handy.

Example - JSON-Schema validation rules

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "title": "Product",
    "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "description": "Name of the product",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "price": {
            "type": "number",
            "exclusiveMinimum": 0
        }
    },
    "required": ["id", "name", "price"]
}
```

Example - Validating an entity using JSON-Schema

```
const JSONValidator = require('jsonschema').Validator;
class Product {
  validate() {
    const v = new JSONValidator();
    return v.validate(this, schema);
  }
  static get schema() {
    //define JSON-Schema, see example above
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to know how to create in nodeJS